# Angular2 bit.ly 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header issue

Tags: angular, cors, bit.ly

I am trying get bit.ly API working, but I got stuck at CORS issues. I checked all the sources I could, but the issue remains.

Angular2 code:

```
getBitLyUrl (fullUrl : string): Observable<string> {


   let headers = new Headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*', 'Accept' : 'application/json' }); 
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 


   let res =  this._http.get('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=a4d0c60f2cfdba6941b9012c76d95a06f8b3765e&longUrl=' 
                  + fullUrl + '&format=json', options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());

    return res;
}
```

Headers from Chrome Network:

```
General:
Request URL:https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?      access_token=a4d0c60f2cfdba6941b9012c76d95a06f8b3765e&longUrl=http://www.cyberma  .net&format=json
 Request Method:OPTIONS
 Status Code:200 OK
 Remote Address:67.199.248.20:443


Response:
Allow:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 25 Jan 2017 10:22:31 GMT
Server:nginx

Request:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en,cs;q=0.8,sk;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, x-xsrf-token
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api-ssl.bitly.com
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,   like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=a4d0c60f2cfdba6941b9012c76d95a06f8b3765e&longUrl=http://www.cyberma.net&format=json.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`let headers = new Headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*', 'Accept' : 'application/json' });` . This is a response header. `CORS` is setup to safe guard the backend server, so these headers have to be set by the backend server in response. If you dont control the server, there is no option to access it from a cross origin unless they approve your domain.

`OPTIONS`  requests are set by browser, not angular. Read more abbout it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control).

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that
>   are permitted to read that information using a web browser.
>   Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on
>   user data (in particular; for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST
>   usage with certain MIME types). The specification mandates that
>   browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from
>   the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request header, and then, upon
>   "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual
>   HTTP request method. Servers can also notify clients whether
>   "credentials" (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should
>   be sent with requests.

Comment: Raj,  when I try their example using plain JS, it does work well.

https://dev.bitly.com/cors.html

The difference between their example and mine is, the request from angular starts with Option. While their example sends GET.

Comment: Drop the `let headers = new Headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*', 'Accept' : 'application/json' });` line and the request will work. As the answer here points out, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a *response* header, not a request header. So don’t send it in a request, ever. Including it in the request is what’s actually [causing your browser to send an OPTIONS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) instead of the GET. And it’s OK to send `Accept: application/json` but the request will also work fine without it.

Comment: It doesn't work. I added the headers just to test it based on some online advice.
I tried jsonp instead. It works on localhost:3000, but not with localhost on wamp. I am a bit desperate here.

Comment: you removed the ``options`` and still gets the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the headers and options arguments from the get function